# How to add a range of IPs in Debian 10?

Tags: debian

I want to add some ranges of extra IPs for Debian 10.
Example: 10.1.1.4 - 254 and 10.1.2.4 - 254

What is the fastest method to add these IP ranges?

I know in CentOS, we just create a file like this:

```
$ nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0-range:1
IPADDR_START=10.1.1.4
IPADDR_END=10.1.1.254
CLONENUM_START=1
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
```

I am not sure how to do this in Debian.

Comment: Have you read this https://www.ducea.com/2006/07/15/linux-tips-how-to-quickly-bind-a-range-of-ips-on-redhat-based-systems/ - it's about extra ranges ? AND this says how to add a single virtual interface (on debian) https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the final use for all these addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `post-up` script in interface definition. See https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5.en.html